# PhpStorm - Why does the highlighting of the html syntax in the string during the concatenation turn off? How to fix?

Tags: phpstorm

There is such a line. HTML in it is highlighted:

```
echo '<input value="1"/>';
```

But if you write like this, then the highlighting turn off:

```
$value = 1;
echo '<input value="'.$value.'"/>';
```

How to fix?

Comment: In the second example there are two strings: `'<input value="'` is not valid HTML and `"/>` can be anything. You cannot ask PhpStorm to predict what will happen during the execution of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @axiac, mentionned, it can only work if there's a single string.

You can make use of PHP's [`heredoc` syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), along with variable interpolation:

```
echo <<<HTML
<input value="{$value}" />
HTML;

// Rest of your code
```

Or you could just close your PHP tag, display your HTML without `echo` and then open it again (if you need to):

```
<?php
$value = 1;
?>

<input value="<?= $value ?>" />

<?php
// Rest of your code
```